I'm trying to include @use _variables.scss in my main file but I keep getting an undefined mixin error
I'm trying to pull in different partials from the bootstrap's scss library. All the other basic files (functions, mixins, and bootstrap) seem to work except when I try to implement the _variables.scss partial. The error that I recieve in my npm cmd is...
Error: Undefined mixin.
    ╷
494 │ @include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");

My code...
@use "/inetpub/wwwroot/assets/MVDA_screenshot/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@use "/inetpub/wwwroot/assets/MVDA_screenshot/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@use "/inetpub/wwwroot/assets/MVDA_screenshot/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@use "/inetpub/wwwroot/assets/MVDA_screenshot/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

It would make sense that I would get this error if I had the wrong file path for "_functions.scss",  or didn't include it at all but when I take the _variables.scss out, my file will then compile. I tried switching the order of when each partial is pulled but that didn't work.
I have also tried adding some extra partials to test such as _root.scss, _variables-dark.scss, and _maps.scss but I get similar results as the _variables.scss partial.
I feel like I'm missing something but I don't know what it is.

Have you forgotten namespaces?

I don't think I need to add namespaces at this point yet because I haven't barrowed anything from these partials. if I added "$secondary: variables.$gray-400;" after my variables module and didn't add the variables namespace, this would make sense. I have stripped back the code to only 4 lines (my code example) and nothing else before compiling to css.
